# How to create psbt to send btc

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

I try to create psbt to send btc from xverse wallet to anouther wallet. I got the problem with sign psbt here is my code

```
const UTXOData = await (
      await fetch(
        `https://blockstream.info/api/address/${this.paymentAddress}/utxo`,
      )
    ).json();

    const hash = UTXOData[0].txid
    const vout = UTXOData[0].vout
    const value = UTXOData[0].value

    const rawTransaction = new bitcoin.Psbt({
      network: bitcoin.networks.bitcoin,
    });

    rawTransaction.addInput({
      hash,
      index: vout,
    });
    rawTransaction.addOutput({
      address: this.paymentAddress,
      value: value,
    });
    rawTransaction.addOutput({
      address: 'RECEIVER ADDRESS',
      value: 1000,
    });

    return rawTransaction.toBase64();
```

But when i try sign this psbt i get error(Transaction Error). I am using the example from [here](https://docs.xverse.app/sats-connect/creating-psbts)